# SQL statement supposed to return more rows

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

My sql statement is a stored procedure that supposed to return the total scores which is grouped by each Agent (rawCSATAgentName)
this is my procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getCSATTeam]
@OtherDate DATE,
@DateToday DATE,
@FullNames nvarchar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;


  SELECT [rawCSATAgentName],

    ( CAST((SUM(case [rawCSATFCR] when 1 then 1 end) + 
    SUM(case [rawCSATFCR] when 0 then 0 when 2 then 0 end)) AS FLOAT)
    /
    (COUNT([rawCSATFCR])) * 100 ) AS [FCR],


   ( CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN [rawCSATHelpfulness] IN (6,7) THEN 1 END) + 
   SUM(CASE WHEN [rawCSATHelpfulness] IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN 0 END)) AS FLOAT)
   /
   (COUNT([rawCSATHelpfulness])) * 100 )
    AS [Helpfulness],


   ( CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN [rawCSATSAK] IN (6,7) THEN 1 END) + 
   SUM(CASE WHEN [rawCSATSAK] IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN 0 END)) AS FLOAT)
   /
   (COUNT([rawCSATSAK])) * 100 )
    AS [SkillsAndKnowledge],


   ( CAST((SUM(CASE WHEN [rawCSATOSR] IN (6,7) THEN 1 END) + 
   SUM(CASE WHEN [rawCSATOSR] IN (0,1,2,3,4,5) THEN 0 END)) AS FLOAT)
   /
   (COUNT([rawCSATOSR])) * 100 )
    AS [OverallSatisfaction]


   FROM [CSATScoresRaw]

   WHERE (convert(varchar(10),[rawCSATDateTime],101) BETWEEN @OtherDate AND @DateToday)
     AND [rawCSATAgentName] IN (SELECT i.str FROM dbo.iter$simple_strlist_to_tbl(@FullNames) AS i)

  GROUP BY [rawCSATAgentName]

  ORDER BY [rawCSATAgentName]

  END
```

But it just return one [rawCSATAgentName] with the total scores. Why?

Comment: Can we see some data? Also, run the SP but return the output of SELECT i.str FROM dbo.iter$simple_strlist_to_tbl(@FullNames) AS i

Comment: Mosty likely because only one of the agents has data "BETWEEN @OtherDate AND @DateToday".  The others are outside of that range?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are more than one row between that date.
By the way, dbo.iter$simple_strlist_to_tbl(@FullNames) just returns the list of agent names delimited with comma (for IN)

Comment: Is @OtherDate always before @DateToday?  it needs to be for this query to work.  And seeing some data and the sample params would help